# Insert rows from select result set except some columns

Tags: mysql

For example this is my table definition :

```
id          int     Auto_Increment
cid_fk      int
name        varchar
number      varchar
```

Also i have these records :

```
id     cid_fk       name        number
1         3         test         A1
1         3         test         A2
.         .          ...         ...
```

Now i want select all of records that the have `cid_fk=3` and insert them with `cid_fk=4` :

```
insert into mytable(cid_fk,name,number)
select (4,name,number) from mytable where cid_fk=3
```

This query works correct but if i want to change my number column for each row how should i do this?
I want my number increase like A3,A4,A5,...

UPDATE

the number value has a static prefix.like qwerty123,qwerty124,qwerty125

Comment: select the last id (as it is autoincrementing), then increment it and concatenate it with A, pass it in your insert query

Comment: @Deepanshu this is an example, number column format isn't related with id.

Comment: is always the number field is prefixed with only 'A'  ?

Comment: @BijuSoman not exactly 'A' but this field has a static prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
set @cnt =0;
insert into mytable(cid_fk,name,number)
select (4,name,concat('A',(@cnt := @cnt + 1) )) from mytable where cid_fk=3
```